# Generate a Hierarchical diagram in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have a BOM structured in a CSV as follows

```
1, Part 1
2, Part 12
2, Part 13
3, Part 123
1, Part 2
2, Part 22
```

Is there some way to create a hierarchical  diagram such as this one in Python? Any help at all would be appreciated!
http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/mysql/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data-1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a [DOT](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) description and render it with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). There are many Python bindings for it: http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php

Answer (score 1):

[pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) is an interface to [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), which is capable of [all sorts of graphs](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php).